# Open view when tap on push Message in swift application

Tags: push-notification, swift5

I m building a iOS application using Swift5. This application is able to receive push message from my php web application using Firebase.

Now I m able to display push message on iPhone when the iphone is locked and the application is not running. Now I can send some type of push message and if the user click on it, the application should be display a view with particular input parameter. But the view is not the same view, can change in base of PushMessage.
For example if you receive push message for whatsup application and click on it, the application show directly the chat of the user and not other chat.

Now this is my code, what can I do to implement it?

```
func configureNotification() {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in }
        }
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching FCM registration token: \(error)")
            } else if let token = token {
                print("FCM registration token: \(token)")
                USER_DEFAULT.set(token, forKey: IOS_TOKEN)
            }
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
       // k.iosRegisterId = deviceTokenString
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        print("APNs device token: \(deviceTokenString)")
       // USER_DEFAULT.set(deviceTokenString, forKey: IOS_TOKEN)

    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("APNs registration failed: \(error)")
        
    }
    
    // MARK:-  Received Remote Notification
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
            Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
            print("main method - \(userInfo)")
      
        if let info = userInfo as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            //let alert1 = info["aps"]!["alert"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            let title = userInfo["gcm.notification.status"] as! String
            hanleNotification(info: info, strStatus: title, strFrom: "Front")
        }

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```